# UK visa cancellation

Tags: visas, uk, payment

I did my online application made the payment and set up an appointment. Two days before the appointment I realised had few errors on my application so I cancelled it and reviewed that cancelation request is in progress. Now trying to reapply and when I get to the payment page it's not allowing me to pay.. Please let me know how long I need to wait

Comment: Keep trying. At some point the previous application will be flushed from the system.